# VBA: Skip cells in range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to fill formulas in column C like this:

```
LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(LastRow, 3)).Formula = "=A1*B1"
```

And it works fine. But is it possible to skip those cells in column C, which value is for example > 0 ?

```
A B C -> A B C
3 2 0    3 2 6
3 4 0    3 4 12
5 6 5    5 6 5  <- this value is not updated
```

Comment: @Mehow: it is possible :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout ++ to your answer and I take my last comment back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it through loop  :

```
    Sub test()

            Dim rngTest As Range
            Dim rngCell As Range

            LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
            Set rngTest = Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(LastRow, 3))
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            For Each rngCell In rngTest.Cells
                If Not rngCell <> "" Then
                    rngCell.Formula = "=" & rngCell.Offset(, -2).Address & "*" & rngCell.Offset(, -1).Address
                End If
            Next
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution has been a bit easier to understand to me. It works fine!

Answer (score 6):

For this you will have to do a slight change to how your data looks like. For example, you need to add "Header" to the first row. The reason we would do that is because we would be using `AutoFilter`

Let's say your data looks like this

[image]

Now use this code

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim copyFrom As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> Get lastrow in column c
        lRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Filter the col C to get values which have 0
        With .Range("C1:C" & lRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=0"

            Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

            '~~> Assign the formula to all the cells in one go
            If Not copyFrom Is Nothing Then _
            copyFrom.Formula = "=A" & copyFrom.Row & "*B" & copyFrom.Row
        End With

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image]